# C# memory handling for methods

Tags: c#, function, memory, methods

I have a question about they way C# functions, or methods, handle memory when certain objects are used as input arguments. I have tried searching for an answer to this but haven't been able to find anything, I might not know what to look for though.

The question: Say I have a really big integer array of size 10.000 by 10.000, called 'MyArray'. Lets say I moreover have some method called 'MyMethod' which takes several entries from two specified rows (this is the input) from MyArray and performs some operations on it, such as adding or multiplying these numbers, and then returns another integer.

To keep my code as short as possible I would prefer to make a method

```
MyMethod(int i, int j, int[][] MyArray)
```

rather than having to enter all the numbers from the array as seperate arguments. However does this mean the method creates a copy of MyArray when it is called or does C# know that if this data is only read and not edited in any way, that making a copy isn't needed?

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference

Comment: @Matthew No, arrays are no passed by reference.  Array types *are* references, and those references are passed by value.  All types are passed by value in C# unless the `ref` or `out` keywords are used.

Comment: @Servy You are technically correct, the best kind of correct.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, arrays are actually objects, and not just addressable regions of contiguous memory as in C and C++. Thus, in our case, only the reference of the array is passed as an argument for the method.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not create a copy as the array will be passed as a reference (like a C++ pointer) to the method. In general only `struct` types will be passed as a copy and normal `class` instances will be passed as a reference.

You can read more on the topic on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here : [MSDN - Passing arrays as argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyfeyz71.aspx)

> Arrays can be passed as arguments to method parameters. Because arrays are reference types, the method can change the value of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are *classes*, and that's why they're just *references* and when we pass array into a method all we need is to pass an address (4 or 8 bytes). Proof:

```
  Boolean isClass = typeof(int[][]).IsClass; // <- return true
```

*Structs* are passed by *value*, e.g. `int` is a *struct*:

```
  Boolean isClass = typeof(int).IsClass; // <- return false;
```